# Mismatched APT Dependencies

Tags: apt, curl, sandbox, synergy

I have Synergy installed on Ubuntu 18.04 (this is not the new version 2, fwiw). Apparently, it has a requirement of `libcurl3`. However, the machine also runs as a hypervisor and I need to use `libguestfs-tools` to access disk images which requires a different version of curl.

So, when I run `apt install libguestfs-tools`, it tries to remove both `libcurl3` and `synergy`. I have stopped it thus far, but am hoping that there might be a way to isolate one or the other into a sandbox or some other alternative method to be able to have both installed simultaneously.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I wasn't sure how to phrase the question.

Answer (score 3):

The whole `libcurl3`/`libcurl4` situation is quite complex, and Ubuntu 18.04 appears to have shipped with a rather unfortunate combination. There is [a bug tracking the issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754294), although it doesn’t seem to have much traction on the Canonical side of things; you could add your feedback there.

[This comment on the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754294/comments/47) gives a workaround:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xapienz/curl34
sudo apt-get update
```

This should allow you to install both `synergy` and `libguestfs-tools` simultaneously.